# How to use some React libraries in a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone

I would like to use React hook and DropZone in a class component.
How should I do?

The error

> src/components/projects/CreateProject.js
> Line 19:14:   React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function      react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
> Line 21:11:   'setUploadfile' is not defined                                                                                                                            no-undef
> Line 52:102:  React Hook "useDropzone" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
> Line 53:7:    'onDrop' is not defined                                                                                                                                   no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
class CreateProject extends Component {
    state = {
        title:'',
        content:'',
        uploadfile:'',
        setUploadfile:''
    }

    onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
      if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
          setUploadfile(acceptedFiles[0]);
      }
    }, []);

    
    handleChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.createProject(this.state)
        this.props.history.push('/')
    }

    handleSubmitImg = (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
      //this.props.sampleteFunction()
    };

    

  render() {
   const maxSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024;
  const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragReject, fileRejections } = useDropzone({
      onDrop,
      accept: 'image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/jpg',
      minSize: 1,
      maxSize,
  });

    const {auth} = this.props

    if(!auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/signin" />
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
            <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">
                Create Project
            </h5>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>

            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="content">Project Content</label>
                <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Create</button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <p>Click</p>
                {this.uploadfile ? <p>File you chose: {this.uploadfile.name}</p> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

const matchStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        createProject: (project) => dispatch(createProject(project))
    }
}

export default connect(matchStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject)
```

Comment: Is it a viable answer for you to rewrite as a function component?

Comment: Absolutely not. I wanted to use dropzone in a class component. Your answer was breath-taking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use hooks (such as `useCallback` or `useDropzone`) inside a class component. They must be used inside the body of a [function component](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) instead.

For this code to work, a few changes must be made. I am supposing you are using the [`react-dropzone`](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) package.

### 1. Remove `setUploadfile` from your state

You are trying to do a `useState` pattern inside a class component. The class component only needs the state declaration and the use of `this.setState` to make updates.

Remove `setUploadfile` from your state. Use `this.setState({ uploadfile: newValue })` instead.

### 2. Remove `useCallback`

The hook `useCallback` is used inside function components to optimize performance and prevent unnecessary renders ([see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)). You made a class component, so there's no need to use memoization for the callback function.

```js
onDrop = acceptedFiles => {
  if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
    this.setState({ uploadfile: acceptedFiles[0] })
  }
}
```

### 3. Use `Dropzone` component rather than `useDropzone` hook

In the documentation of `react-dropzone` there's an alternative for `useDropzone` hook. The [`Dropzone`](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#src) component.

Remove the `useDropzone` hook.

```html
<Dropzone
  onDrop={this.onDrop}
  accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg"
  minSize={1}
  maxSize={maxSize}
>
  {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
    <div className="container">{/* The rest of your code */}</div>
  )}
</Dropzone>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use react hooks inside a Class component, either use class or functional component.

Answer (score 0):

To use useCallback in a class component, use `bind(this)` property

Comment: Actually, you cannot use any hook outside the body of a function component. See the [documentation about this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).